# MariaDB: LOAD DATA INFILE with dynamic_columns

Tags: mysql, mariadb, load-data-infile

I have a table that looks like this (using MariaDB):

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
  ,c_id varchar(40) NULL
  ,email varchar(150) NULL
  ,dynamic_columns BLOB NULL
  ,created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
  ,updated_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp ON UPDATE current_timestamp
);
```

I'm loading data from some legacy tables into this table and I'm making use of MariaDB's `dynamic_columns` to store up to 3 dynamic columns based on the which legacy table.
(https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/nosql/dynamic-columns/)

I'd like to use `LOAD DATA INFILE` to quickly/bulk to insert the legacy data into the new table, but I can't figure out how to do that with dynamic columns.

Searching Google has turned up zilch.

Comment: Old question, I know, but I just asked a similar question before finding this. Every work out a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic columns are stored in an internal binary format. To create or change a dynamic column outside of MariaDB server you should use the Dynamic column API of MariaDB Connector/C:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/dynamic-columns-api/

You will also find some examples in the test suite of Connector/C:

https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-connector-c/blob/master/unittest/libmariadb/dyncol.c